# Collect puzzle from curve fragments

Tags: curve-fitting, piecewise

I have a data, which consists of a number of chunks. I now that they come from some continuous curve, but later were shifted in the y-direction. Now I want to shift them back to estimate original curve. Some parts are not shifted, but just absent. To clarify the situation dummy code to generate something similar is below (Matlab):

```
%% generate some dummy data
knots = rand(10,2);
% fix starting and stop points
knots = [[0,rand()];knots;[1,rand()]];
% sort knots
knots=unique(knots,'rows');
% generate dummy curve
dummyX = linspace(0,1,10^4);
dummyY = interp1(knots(:,1),knots(:,2),dummyX,'spline');
figure()
subplot(2,1,1)
plot(dummyX,dummyY)
%% Add offset and wipe some parts
% get borders of chunks
borders = [1;randi([1,numel(dummyX)],20,1);numel(dummyX)];
borders = unique(borders);
borders = [borders(1:end-1)+1,borders(2:end)];
borders(1) = 1;
% add ofsets or nans
offset = (rand(size(borders,1),1)-0.5)*5;
offset(randperm(numel(offset),floor(size(borders,1)/3)))=nan;
for iBorder = 1:size(borders,1)
   idx = borders(iBorder,1): borders(iBorder,2);
   dummyY(idx)=dummyY(idx)+offset(iBorder);
   dummyY(idx([1,end]))=nan;
end
subplot(2,1,2)
plot(dummyX,dummyY)
```

[image]

Original curve is on top, shifted on the bottom. I try to shift chunks pairwise, minimizing the length of the cubic spline, but it did not work for me. I understand, that it is impossible to obtain absolutely same curve (I may lose some peaks).

**Could You help me to find the best shifts?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had several ideas for this and played with overall curvature, arc length, etc. as well as mixed combinations. Turned out that a simple `chi**2` works best. So it goes as simple as this:

1. Get some knots to fit every chunk with a given precision by splines
2. join everything
3. reduce knots to avoid very close knots in touching sets, those can result in large curvature.
4. use leastsq fit on entire set with splines on joined and reduced set of knots to find shifts.

In theory one could play with / modify:

- spline order
- min knot density
- max knot density
- how adjacent sets are dealt with
- adding a knot to a large gap
- etc.

(**Note**: In some random data the splrev produced error messages. As those are mostly not very helpful, I can only say that this code is not 100% robust.)

Code is as follows

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d, splrep, splev
from scipy.optimize import fmin, leastsq

def reduce_knots( inList, dist ):
    outList=[]
    addList=[]
    for i in inList:
        try:
            if abs( i - addList[ -1 ] ) < dist:
                addList += [ i ]
            else:
                outList += [ addList ]
                addList = [ i ]
        except IndexError:### basically the first
            addList = [ i]
    outList += [ addList ]
    return [ sum( x ) / len( x ) for x in outList ]

def adaptive_knots( inX, inY, thresh=.005 ):
    ll = len( inX )
    sup = ll - 4
    assert sup > 3
    nN = 3
    test = True
    while test:
        testknots = np.linspace( 1, len( inX ) - 2, nN, dtype=np.int )
        testknots = [ inX[ x ] for x in testknots ]
        myTCK= splrep( inX , inY, t=testknots )
        newY = splev( inX , myTCK )
        chi2 = np.sum( ( newY - inY )**2 ) / ll
        if chi2 > thresh:
            nN += 1
            if nN > sup:
                test = False
        else:
            test = False
    return testknots

def global_residuals( shiftList, xBlocks, yBlocks, allTheKnots ):# everything shifted (1 is redundant by global offset) Blocks must be ordered an np.arrays
    localYBlocks = [ s + yList for s, yList in zip( shiftList, yBlocks ) ]
    allTheX = np.concatenate( xBlocks )
    allTheY = np.concatenate( localYBlocks )
    tck = splrep( allTheX, allTheY, t=allTheKnots )
    yList  = splev( allTheX, tck )
    diff = yList - allTheY
    return diff

#~ np.random.seed( 28561 )
np.random.seed( 5561 )
#~ np.random.seed( 733437 )

### python way for test data
knots = np.random.rand( 8, 2 )
knots = np.array( sorted( [ [ 0, np.random.rand() ] ] + list( knots ) + [ [ 1, np.random.rand() ] ], key=lambda x: x[ 0 ] ) )
dummyX = np.linspace( 0, 1, 3e4 )
f = interp1d( knots[ :, 0 ], knots[ :, 1 ], 'cubic' )
dummyY = np.fromiter( ( f( x ) for x in dummyX ), np.float )
chunk = np.append( [ 0 ], np.append( np.sort( np.random.randint( 7, high=len( dummyX ) - 10 , size= 10, dtype=np.int ) ), len( dummyX ) ) )

xDataDict = dict()
yDataDict = dict()
allX = np.array( [] )
allY = np.array( [] )
allK = np.array( [] )
allS = []

for i, val in enumerate(chunk[ : -1 ] ):
    if np.random.rand() < .75: ## 25% of not appearing
        xDataDict[ i ] = dummyX[ val:chunk[ i + 1 ] ]
        realShift = 1.5 * ( 1 - 2 * np.random.rand() )
        allS += [ realShift ]
        yDataDict[ i ] = dummyY[ val:chunk[ i + 1 ] ] + realShift
        yDataDict[ i ] = np.fromiter( ( np.random.normal( scale=.05, loc=y ) for y in yDataDict[ i ] ), np.float )
        allX = np.append( allX, xDataDict[ i ] )
        allY = np.append( allY, yDataDict[ i ] )

### Plotting
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot( 3, 1, 1 )
ax.plot( knots[ :, 0 ],knots[ :, 1 ], ls='', c='r', marker='o')
ax.plot( dummyX , dummyY, '--' )
for key in xDataDict.keys():
    ax.plot(xDataDict[ key ], yDataDict[ key ] )
    myKnots = adaptive_knots( xDataDict[ key ], yDataDict[ key ] )
    allK = np.append( allK, myKnots )
    myTCK = splrep( xDataDict[ key ], yDataDict[ key ], t=myKnots )
    ax.plot( xDataDict[ key ], splev( xDataDict[ key ] , myTCK ) )
myTCK = splrep( allX, allY, t=allK )
ax.plot( allX, splev( allX, myTCK ) )
for x in allK:
    ax.axvline( x=x, linestyle=':', color='#AAAAAA', linewidth=1 )

### now fitting
myXBlockList = []
myYBlockList = []
for key in sorted( xDataDict.keys() ):
     myXBlockList += [ xDataDict[ key ] ]
     myYBlockList += [ yDataDict[ key ] ]

#start values
s = [ 0 ]
for i,y in enumerate( myYBlockList[ :-1 ] ):
    ds = myYBlockList[ i + 1 ][ 0 ] - y[ -1 ]
    s += [ -ds ]
startShift = np.cumsum( s )

allK = reduce_knots( allK, .01 )

sol, ierr = leastsq( global_residuals, x0=startShift, args=( myXBlockList, myYBlockList, allK ), maxfev=10000 )
sol = np.array(sol) - sol[ 0 ]
print "solution: ", -sol
print "real: ", np.array( allS ) - allS[ 0 ]

### Plotting solutions
bx = fig.add_subplot( 3, 1, 3, sharex=ax )
for x, y, s in zip( myXBlockList, myYBlockList, sol ):
    bx.plot( x, y + s )

localYBlocks = [ s + yList for s,yList in zip( sol, myYBlockList ) ]
allTheX = np.concatenate( myXBlockList )
allTheY = np.concatenate( localYBlocks )
tck = splrep( allTheX, allTheY, t=allK )
dx = allTheX[ 1 ] - allTheX[ 0 ]
testX = np.arange( allTheX[ 0 ], allTheX[ -1 ], dx )
finalyList  = splev( testX, tck)
bx.plot( testX, finalyList , 'k--' )

mean = sum( dummyY ) / len( dummyY ) - sum( finalyList ) / len( finalyList )

bx.plot( dummyX, dummyY - mean, '--' )
for x in allK:
    bx.axvline( x=x, linestyle=':', color='#AAAAAA', linewidth=1 )

cx = fig.add_subplot( 3, 1, 2, sharex=ax )
for x, y, s in zip( myXBlockList, myYBlockList, startShift ):
    cx.plot( x, y + s )

plt.show()
```

For small gaps this works nicely on the test data

[image: seed 5561]
The upper graph shows the original spline and its knots as red dots. This generated the data. Moreover, it shows the noisy shifted chunks, the initial fitting knots as vertical lines and an according spline fit.
Mid graph shows the chunks shifted by the pre-calculated start values - aligned ends. 
Lower graph shows original spline, fitted spline, reduced knot positions, and chunks shifted according to the fit solution.

Naturally, the larger the gaps the more the solution deviates from the original

[image: seed 733437]

...but still quite good.